# Activity onResume()

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am writing a **Shopping Cart App** in which i am **allowing user to choose items to buy and add their required items to Cart**, for this i have given two different tabs,

*First Tab*, to browse products

*Second Tab*, to browse Items in Cart [User Added]

Here I am facing a small problem. I am *not getting updated quantity in Cart*, but **getting changes in total price**, whenever i *do change in Item Quantity*.

So, tell me what I need to add in my code to get changes in Quantity also, **How to Update Quantity while moving between Tabs**

I have written below code in onResume() under ViewCartActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() == 0) 
    {
        return;
    }

    Double mGTotal = Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(0).get(SingleTrackActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
    for (int i = 1; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) 
    {   
    mGTotal = mGTotal + Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(SingleTrackActivity.KEY_TOTAL));
    }
    mGrandTotal = String.valueOf(mGTotal);
    mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
    myTextVeiwGrandTotal.setText(mGrandTotal);
    mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(mGTotal));
    mTotal = String.valueOf(Constants.mItem_Detail.size());
    mItems.setText(mTotal);
}
```

Please see below screen shot, i have updated quantity of an item from 1 to 10, therefore i got changes in Total Amount, but did not get any change in Quantity getting 1 only,whenever i am moving between tabs i am facing this problem:

[image]

Using Below code in Products.java class to update quantity of an Item:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) {
                                            if (Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(TAG_NAME)
                                                    .equals(song_name)) {
                                                Constants.mItem_Detail.remove(i);
                                                break;}
```

**Note:**

If i will not move to Cart Tab from Products Tab, I am able to view changes in Quantity of an Item, but once i will move to Cart Tab from Products Tab then i am not getting changes in Quantity of an Item...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are on right path, just check with patience, add items to cart then update cart items, wait for few seconds, i hope it will update your cart itself.....

Your code looks like good to me:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) {
        if (Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(TAG_NAME)
        .equals(song_name)) {
        Constants.mItem_Detail.remove(i);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have implemented the tabs as fragments.
If this is true then you need to move the onResume() method from the Activity to the Fragment.

Reference link to fragment lifecycle: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html